# Disable developer mode extensions pop up chrome54

Tags: google-chrome

I just upgrade to chrome 54 and iu'm getting this anoy pop up every time i launch chrome
I tried to use this solution:

run hiew32 demo (in admin mode) and open Chrome.dll
switch to hex view (Enter key)
search for ExtensionDeveloperModeWarning (F7)
press F3 to edit and replace the first letter "E" with any other character
save (F9).

BUT
 the string ExtensionDeveloperModeWarning is not present anymore in chrome.dll
So I search and replace any string with the word Warning for larning, and still is not working.

So the problem still exist

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Write a Script to open a new window as soon as chrome is opened and then close the old window.

Add the following code to your background java script file.

```
chrome.windows.create({type: 'normal',focused: true, state: 'maximized'}, function(window) {
                 chrome.windows.getAll( function(windows)
                 {
                     for(var i=0;i<windows.length;i++)
                     {
                         if(windows[i].id!=window.id)
                         {
                             chrome.windows.remove(windows[i].id);
                         }
                     }

                 });
             } );
```

Note: To work as expected, after adding/installing the extension to chrome, restart chrome manually

Answer (score 1):

it is not a universal solution, but there is a way for specific extensions by using the whitelist. Add [the chromium adm template](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates) into the gpedit.msc, and add the ID of the develop mode extensions. Apply and restart chrome. It should be OK.

The solution can both prevent the pop-up warning and give you the permission to use some extensions not in the webstore. If you can use the develop mode extensions but suffer from the pop-up warning, it also can help you.

Sadly Stackoverflow doesn't permit me to post images and too many links, so I have to put relavant things in my blog.

http://yutouyes.blogspot.com/2016/12/using-crx-extensions-added-offline-in.html

Wish it can help.

I've tried several methods but only the one above worked.